# Android-Get continent name by country name

Tags: android

I am able to get single country name from an array.What will be the best way to get continent name from which this country belongs to?Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look for a list in the internet and load that from your assets directory. Do you have the ISO 3166 Country Code, or just the name? If you have just the name, you could run into troubles when countries in the list are spelled in a different language.

Quick googling returned this:

http://countrylist.net/

Comment: ,OK i will use CSV but is there any API,so we post name and this will return continent name.

Comment: Probably, you have to google. But what's the benefit of using an API? It's slower, it could be down and you could get over usage-limits and be banned. Countries don't change that often, do they?

Comment: ,Thanks I did solve problem by filling continent vise arrays of  countries names...